# Python CURL delete request function

Tags: python, csv, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to recreate this CURL request in Python and get it to loop through a CSV.

```
curl -X "DELETE" --user 'api:<my-api-key>' \   https://api.mailgun.net/v3/messages.thewebsite/unsubscribes \  
-F address='email@gmail.com'
```

I'm thinking I should create a function and return the result. I'm using the requests package along with CSV but getting the output of

<function remove_suppression at 0x7fb3935baf70> printed to the console. What am I missing here?

Code sample below.

```
Import csv
Import requests


def remove_suppression():
    return requests.delete(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/messages.thewebsite.com/unsubscribes",
        auth=("api", "key-abcdefg12345789gbb"),
        data={'address':'row[1]'})

with open('/Users/brett/Downloads/example.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
            try:
                
                remove_suppression()
                print("=========================")
                print(remove_suppression.text)
                sleep(5)
 
            except:

            #write log to a text file
```

Comment: Just a note, but remember to ensure that's not an actual api key in the question. I also suggested an edit.

Comment: Instead of using `print(remove_suppression.text)`, can you save the return value of `remove_suppression()`, and print that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `row` value as a parameter to `remove_supression`. Currently you're printing out the value of `remove_suppression`, which is a function.

You should replace the top of your function with:

```py
def remove_supression(row): ...
```

Make sure to also replace the `'row[1]'` part with just `row`, as otherwise you're just sending the literal string `'row[1]'` instead of the actual row.

On top of this, you need to assign the value you get from `remove_supression(row)` inside the for loop to a value, which you can then use to get the text from, e.g.:

```py
resp = remove_supression(row)
print(resp.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't printing the result but string representation of function object. Store the result to variable and print the variable. For example:

```py
import csv
import requests


def remove_suppression():
    return requests.delete(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/messages.thewebsite.com/unsubscribes",
        auth=("api", "key-abcdefg12345789gbb"),
        data={"address": "row[1]"},
    )


with open("/Users/brett/Downloads/example.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in readCSV:
        try:
            result = remove_suppression().text # <-- store the .text result
            print("=========================")
            print(result)  # <-- print it
            sleep(5)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Or alternatively `result = remove_suppression()` and then `print(result.text)`.